# Count the sum of outputs

Tags: anylogic

I have created an agent type named "Process" with a basic flow process inside (source-process-sink), in that agent i added a data output (named Treated) that counts the number of agents that went through the sink.
Now in my main i've put a population of that agent "Process" (lets say a population of 10)

my goal is to create a chart that shows the number counted by the data output of every agent of the "Process" population i tried to do a sum function { sum(Process.Treated, p ->p.count())} but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

1. To know how many agent passes in the `sink` block of the "Process" `Population`, you do not have to count. It is enough for you to access the data in the `sink` block itself in the following way: `process_population(index).sink.count()`
2. You can use a bar chart to display for each member of your population the amount of agents that have left the sink block:

> ```
> DataItem myDataItem = new DataItem();
> for (int i = 0 ; i < process_population.size() ; i++)
> {
>   myDataItem.setValue(process_population(i).sink.count());
>   MychartBar.addDataItem(myDataItem, "Titel" , Color);
> }
> MychartBar.updateData();
> ```

If you really want to invest and you want to add an X-axis with labels with the name or the index of each agent in your `population`, you can do the following instructions:

1. Put text labels below your chart bar in the lower left corner.
2. Define the Replication property for it as the population size: `process_population.size()`.
3. For its X position property use the following code:

> ```
> MychartBar.getX((MychartBar.getWidth()/(process_population.size()-1))*index
> ```

4. Under the Text property, you can put `index + 1` to get the index of the agent or put any variable that is inside the agent, for example its name `process_population(index).name`

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much, i though i cant modify the Main.java file so where can i put the code you have written.?

Comment: You can put the code wher you need, for exampel: on startup of the main, on a click button event etc.